# Excel VBA to web form date format

Tags: excel, vba, date, internet-explorer, date-formatting

Doing my first VBA to fill in a web form in IE. Having some issue with date from excel changing format when it is put in the web field.

```
 Set doc = ie.document

doc.getElementById("txtTrackNotes").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value

doc.getElementById("txtEntryTrackConnote").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

doc.getElementById("txtTrackDate").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
```

The last line there is the one causing problem. The Value in C2 is a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy

When it goes into the webform it comes up in the format dd MONTH (in text) yyyy 00:00  (for example 1 January 2018 00:00)

Source HTML is

```
<input name="txtTrackDate" class="Size9" id="txtTrackDate" style="width: 100px;" onclick="javascript:displayDatePicker('txtTrackDate');" onblur="javascript:CheckDate(this.value);" type="text" value="25/10/2018">
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=Format$(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Is the field expecting this input format? If the above still changes then verify what the expected format is for the field.

Comment: Also, check the source cell formatting is as expected.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!  And yes the cell was formatted as a short date in excel and the same format was expected in the input field